# TGPImage with transparent color?

Tags: delphi, transparency, gdi+

```
headingGPImage := TGPImage.Create('heading.bmp');
```

the `heading.bmp` image has no true transparency, but one of the colors should be considered as transparent. How to do this with TGPImage so that it will be transferred with

```
var
  GPGraphics: TGPGraphics;
begin
  GPGraphics.DrawImage(headingGPImage, slider3.Position * 4, 200);
end;
```

using transparent color?

Answer (score 0):

Works for png and bmp with white background:

```
var dest: TGPRect;

attr := TGPImageAttributes.Create;
attr.SetColorKey($FFFFFF, $FFFFFF);
dest.X := 0;
dest.Y := 0;
dest.Width := headingGPImage.GetWidth;
dest.Height := headingGPImage.GetHeight;
GPGraphics.DrawImage(headingGPImage, dest,
     0, 0, Round(headingGPImage.GetWidth), Round(headingGPImage.GetHeight), 
     UnitPixel, 
     attr);
```

Comment: It is very strange, but the heading image disappeared.

Comment: What if remove all arguments and use only drawimage with x,y?

Comment: `GPGraphics.DrawImage(headingGPImage, slider3.Position * 4, 200, headingGPImage.GetWidth(), headingGPImage.GetHeight());` works, but not transparent. I decided to draw a transparent PNG image out of BMP. It works with a simpler version of `DrawImage`.

Comment: For me grayscale bitmap worked too. With color key range 0..$808080 all dark gray colors were tranparent